# Swift + Apollo GraphQL Integration Issue

Tags: swift, apollo, apollo-client

Below is the script which I am inserting under "Xcode > Build Phases" to generate API.swift file where I was able to create schema.json file successfully through Apollo client and then added .graphql file with query to run as well.

Project Architecture:

- Swift (iOS)
- Apollo Graphql (API)
- MySQL

```
DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE="${BUILD_ROOT}"

while ! [ -d "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}/SourcePackages" ]; do
  if [ "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}" = / ]; then
    echo >&2
    exit 1
  fi

  DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE="$(dirname "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}")"
done


SCRIPT_PATH="${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}/SourcePackages/checkouts/apollo-ios/scripts"

if [ -z "${SCRIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo >&2 
    exit 1
fi

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
"${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./**/LaunchList.graphql --localSchemaFile="schema.json" API.swift
```

Build is successful but no API.swift file is getting generated. I even created blank API.swift file but it is NOT getting updated as well.

What am I missing here?